# Is there a better way than this in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, append

Reversing an Array Challenge: is there a better way and shorted method in the below code? **without using external modules just logic/functions**

```
numA = []
    
    for num in range(6):
        numA.append(num)
        
    x = numA[::-1]
    
    for nums in x:
        print('*'*nums)
```

Comment: Not sure what "better" means. A different way would be `print('\n'.join('*' * n for n in range(6)[::-1]))` (assuming `numA` is redundant in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for nums in range(6):
    print('*'*( 5- nums))
```

Comment: I like this method

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37637857/7493063), it's probably more efficient to call `.reverse()` on your array. You just need to keep in mind that these work different than each other, one creates a new array and does not mutate the original object but `.reverse()` reverses the object that you use it on.

Answer (score 0):

```
numA = []
for num in range(6)[::-1]:
    numA.append(num)
    print('*'*num)
```

I am a beginner, and this is what I can come up with right now.
The `[::-1]` after the range reverses it so you can combine both loops.
I'm not sure why you need the array in this, just because the same result can be achieved if you comment out the 1st and 3rd lines.

Comment: Hey nice one but even a better way
Using  just 2 lines 
for num in range(6)[::-1]:
    print('*'*num)